# Why am I getting an error, "ReferenceError: categories is not defined" in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

In my understanding, $scope.categories is already defined. Then why am I getting this error and not able to access data from the Json file?

Here is my controller:

```
(function(){

    app.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', '$http', function($scope,$cookies,$http){

        $http.get("controllers/data.json").then(function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
        }); 

        $scope.specials = [categories[0].laptops[1], categories[1].accessories[0]];

    }]);

})();
```

Here is my Json file:

```
[
  {
    "laptops": [     
      {
        "name": "Asus Laptop",
        "price": 300
      },
      {
        "name": "HP Notebook",
        "price": 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "accessories": [
      {
        "name": "WD Hard Drive",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "name": "WD Blue SSD",
        "price": 700
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: There are a couple things you need to be aware of. First, I assume you are getting this error on the line that starts with `$scope.specials = ...`, right? The `categories` identifier you reference in that line is not the same as `$scope.categories`. Second, the line of code that assigns the value to `$scope.categories` will get executed *after* the line that assigns `$scope.specials`. This is because `$http.get` is an *asynchronous* process. This is a very important thing to understand when working with JavaScript.

Comment: You probably need to move the line that assigns `$scope.specials` into the callback function, right under the line that assigns `$scope.categories`.

Comment: I tried moving the line that assigns $scope.specials into the callback function, right under the line that assigns $scope.categories and ran into more errors.

Comment: Did you fix the other problem I mentioned? You're referring to `categories` but you probably mean `$scope.categories`.

Comment: Thank you, I did fix the problem with your help and others who responded. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned response data into `$scope.categories`, you need to use `$scope.categories` instead of `categories` and also you should add into `$scope.specials` once http call completed like

```
(function(){

    app.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', '$http', function($scope,$cookies,$http){

        $scope.specials = [];
        $http.get("controllers/data.json").then(function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
            $scope.specials.push($scope.categories[0].laptops[1]);
            $scope.specials.push($scope.categories[1]. accessories[0]);
        }); 

        

    }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a few issues here. First is you never define a variable named categories, you have a property of the $scope object named that, so you need to access `$scope.categories` or the `response.data` setting it directly.

Second, you have a race condition issue. You are trying to access the values of categories outside the promise, meaning potentially before the get request has returned any data. When you use `get().then()` like you are, the code after the request doesn't wait for the request to finish before it runs, so whatever is faster runs first. Because one of the two operations running is accessing an external endpoint and the other is local javascript code, the flow is almost guaranteed to be this:

1. send get request to "controllers/data.json"
2. set $scope.specials - causing your undefined error
3. set $scope.categories when get request promise resolves

You need to access the categories inside the promise to guarantee that it actually has been defined at the point you are trying to access it:

```
$http.get("controllers/data.json").then(function (response) {
    $scope.categories = response.data;
    $scope.specials = [$scope.categories[0].laptops[1], $scope.categories[1].accessories[0]];
});
```

It's also generally a bad idea to hard code indexes like this, if the data changes you run into a possible index out of bounds error.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However, how do I go around hard coding indexes in situations where I only need to access a few specific items from a large array of items?

Comment: @MDube it's a pretty awkward structure to your json, and it's probably fine for your purpose (this looks like early college work) but you'd usually search for the key you want in the elements of the array. The way you have it here requires you know exactly what will be where in the json arrays - something you never assume when querying an endpoint.

I wouldn't have the categories be an array, just an object with properties for each category, so you'd just access the categories as `$scope.categories?.laptops?.[1]`. With what you have it's best to do `$scope.categories?.[0]?.laptops?.[1]`

Comment: The truth is I'm teaching myself  Angularjs through trial and error, with no solid foundation or any proper guidance.

Comment: @MDube you should treat the data as if it came from a database query, even though I'm guessing it came from a static json file you control the content of. I'd suggest dropping the outermost array so it's `{ laptops: [ { }, { } ], accessories: [ { }, { } ] }` and writing a quick function where you pass the name and type of object you need that goes through the array to return the right object or null and call it for the "HP notebook" and "WD Hard Drive". same result, a bit slower, but doesn't assume knowing what will be where in the object.